# Is UICollectionView suitable for what I want to achieve?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

My app is based on 'Fantasy Football'.

In this app I want to display a table with 4 or 5 columns:

Position | Team | Win % | Form |etc

I currently have a UITableView displaying the Teams.  This was done as a first step as to making sure my API is working.

The Form cells will be a series of 6 small coloured circles representing the last 6 matches; red for loss, amber for draw, green for wins.

Should I use a UICollectionView to achieve this scenario?

My concern is that each cell in row needs to be related to each other, and what I've seen so far about UICollectionView is its for displaying 'unrelated' items whose position in the grid doesn't really matter.  i.e images.

Am I right in continuing down the UICollectionView path or is there something else I should be looking at?

Please see fig.3 on screen 2 for an example of how i want it to look.

[image: Table on Screen 2]

Comment: if you want an opinion just for `fig. 3` on `Screen 2` then I would suggest that you use a `UITableView` instead of a `UICollectionView`. Make two prototype cells one two show the first row only and another to show the list under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using [collection view](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview) the display of columns will not be same in different sizes. Also, increase in the number of columns (say by one) will cause extra effort in figuring out the size of the cell to adjust the view (if you are using one cell for one column data representation).

I think you should use [table view](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) with [custom cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) as per your requirement of number of columns (embedded in one cell)

This may look something like:
[image: Custom cell]